# There is any way to insert data into an IndexedDB pointing to the file

Tags: javascript, database, browser, nosql, indexeddb

I need to insert data in a IndexedDB, but not in the browser context. Pointing directly to the IndexedDB file. I have access to that file

There is any module/library that allow me to do that?

I tried several way but I couldn't manage to do it.

Comment: Please add the ways that you have tried, this might help others to answer your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.